# Position an element from its normal left to the most right place

Tags: css

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/Gqufq/ and I want to position the second input right after (in the same line) of the first and end it to the right of the div.

How to do this with CSS, without put an explicit dimension on the first input? (Also, the div may have a variable width)

```
div { width: 200px; background-color: gray; }

<div>
    <input size="5" />
    <input />
</div>
```

Comment: So far, none solutions presented are effective. I just want the second input to flow from its current default position up to the right. And if I increase the div width, it must continue doing this correctly.

Comment: make sure you test the right jsfiddleS and do not mix them up ;)

Answer (score 2):

add `size` attribute to 2nd input box also.

Comment: No, he doesn't got the question.

Answer (score 2):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Gqufq/1/

```
  div { width: 200px; 
background-color: gray; 
display:inline;
padding:5px; }
```

Comment: This makes the default input width influence the div width, instead the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `position: absolute` for 2nd input.  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gqufq/3/)

But it won't look good.  so change the width of the `div` as `width: 100%`

Comment: Also not sure you want to move the 2nd div to rightmost but try this http://jsfiddle.net/Gqufq/10/

Comment: @AdrianodosSantosFernandes Can you explain in brief your explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The use of float technic and labels will do it: http://jsfiddle.net/H3YQ3/1/ , http://jsfiddle.net/H3YQ3/2/

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin:1em;
}
label {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
label:first-child {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
}
input {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.big {
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: Extending the div width does not have the effect I want.

Comment: no div is being extended it remains the 200px you have setted , what do you mean ? I understood , one line 1 input on each side . ypour 200px are in the first place not wide enough to hold 2 inputs. Your are missing clarity in code shown and effect wanted. ;)

Comment: I still believe first answer was the one you where looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/Gqufq/6/ make sure you tested the right jsfiddle :) justify and floats have the same limit: widths of div or input must be controled so input have room to stand on one line max or min-width depending wich you want to control.

Comment: Look at this new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H3YQ3/ I can change only the table width and the layout will adapt. I also can change only the first td width and it will adapt too. I want this with only CSS. A field with a size, and next a field who fills the remaining space.

Comment: oki, what about using float technic and labels http://jsfiddle.net/H3YQ3/1/ http://jsfiddle.net/H3YQ3/2/